# Unescape unicode in character string

Tags: regex, json, r, unicode, utf-8

There is a long standing [bug](https://github.com/duncantl/RJSONIO/issues/6) in `RJSONIO` for parsing json strings containing unicode escape sequences. It seems like the bug needs to be fixed in `libjson` which might not happen any time soon, so I am looking in creating a workaround in R which unescapes `\uxxxx` sequences before feeding them to the json parser.

Some context: json data is always unicode, using `utf-8` by default, so there is generally no need for escaping. But for historical reasons, json does support escaped unicode. Hence the json data

```
{"x" : "Zürich"}
```

and

```
{"x" : "Z\u00FCrich"}
```

are equivalent and should result in exactly the same output when parsed. But for whatever reason, the latter doesn't work in `RJSONIO`. Additional [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223795/how-to-correctly-deal-with-escaped-unicode-characters-in-r-e-g-the-em-dash) is caused by the fact that R itself supports escaped unicode as well. So when we type `"Z\u00FCrich"` in an R console, it is automatically correctly converted to `"Zürich"`. To get the actual json string at hand, we need to escape the backslash itself that is the first character of the unicode escape sequence in json:

```
test <- '{"x" : "Z\\u00FCrich"}'
cat(test)
```

So my question is: given a large json string in R, how can I unescape all escaped unicode sequences? I.e. how do I replace all occurrences of `\uxxxx` by the corresponding unicode character? Again, the `\uxxxx` here represents an actual string of 6 characters, starting with a backslash. So an `unescape` function should satisfy:

```
#Escaped string
escaped <- "Z\\u00FCrich"

#Unescape unicode
unescape(escaped) == "Zürich"

#This is the same thing
unescape(escaped) == "Z\u00FCrich"
```

One thing that might complicate things is that if the backslash itself is escaped in json with another backslash, it is **not** part of the unicode escape sequence. E.g. `unescape` should also satisfy:

```
#Watch out for escaped backslashes
unescape("Z\\\\u00FCrich") == "Z\\\\u00FCrich"
unescape("Z\\\\\\u00FCrich") == "Z\\\\ürich"
```

Comment: I had a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067206/reading-unescaped-backslashes-in-json-into-r Not sure if there's any easy solution.

Comment: That's a different problem. You are trying to parse invalid JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After playing with this some more I think the best I can do is searching for `\uxxxx` patterns using a regular expression, and then parse those using the R parser:

```
unescape_unicode <- function(x){
  #single string only
  stopifnot(is.character(x) && length(x) == 1)

  #find matches
  m <- gregexpr("(\\\\)+u[0-9a-z]{4}", x, ignore.case = TRUE)

  if(m[[1]][1] > -1){
    #parse matches
    p <- vapply(regmatches(x, m)[[1]], function(txt){
      gsub("\\", "\\\\", parse(text=paste0('"', txt, '"'))[[1]], fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)
    }, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

    #substitute parsed into original
    regmatches(x, m) <- list(p)
  }

  x
}
```

This seems to work for all cases and I haven't found any odd side effects yet

Answer (score 2):

There is a function for this in [`stringi`](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/) package  :)

```
require(stringi)    
escaped <- "Z\\u00FCrich"
escaped
## [1] "Z\\u00FCrich"
stri_unescape_unicode(escaped)
## [1] "Zürich"
```

Comment: This fails the latter tests because it also unescapes the newlines, tabs, backslashses, etc. However `json` needs those to stay escaped. I **only** want to unescape the `\u` sequences, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
\"x\"\s:\s\"([^"]*?)\"
```

This is not looking letters. Just waiting for a quote