# Converting encoding of deparsed strings

Tags: r, string, text, utf-8

I have the following vector:

```
x <- list("Chamberlain", "\"Roma\\u00F1ach\"", "<node>")
```

I want to convert it a vector with unicode character replaced with the UTF-8, like so:

```
goal <- list("Chamberlain", "Romañach", "<node>")
```

The deparsed string is causing problems. If the second string was instead:

```
wouldbenice <- "Roma\u00F1ach"
```

Then `enc2native(wouldbenice)` would do the right thing.  (or `lapply(x, enc2native)` for the whole string.

I can get the second string to display correctly in UTF-8 with:

```
# displays "Romañach"
eval(parse(text = x[[2]]))
```

However, this goes poorly (throws parse errors) with `x[1]` and `x[2]`.  How can I reliably parse the entire list into the appropriate encoding?

Comment: Related: [*Unescape unicode in character string*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24952174/2204410)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `stringi` package.

From `stringi` use `stri_replace_all_regex` for replacement and `stri_unescape_unicode` to unescape Unicode symbols.

```
library(stringi)

x <- list("Chamberlain", "\"Roma\\u00F1ach\"", "<node>")

removed_quotes <- stri_replace_all_regex(x, "\"", "")

unescaped <- stri_unescape_unicode(removed_quotes)

# [1] "Chamberlain" "Romañach"    "<node>"
```

Comment: If you want, you can use `stri_replace_all_regex(str = x, pattern = "\"", replacement = "")`. `stri_replace_all_regex` is a function in the stringi package.

Answer (score 2):

This satisfies the objective in base R, but seems less than ideal in other ways.  Putting it here so readers can compare, though I think the `stringi`-based solution is probably the way to go.

```
utf8me <- function(x){ 
  i <- grepl('\\u', x) # Not a robust way to detect a unicode char?
  x[i] <- eval(parse(text=x[i])) # 
  x
  }

lapply(x, utf8me)
```