# Decode utf8 to regular characters in python/R

Tags: python, r, encoding, utf

I have various strings such as e.g. `xc3\x93\xc5\x81` those are encoded UTF-8 characters. The only file i have access to is with those encoded values. How can I decode this in either R or python to regular characters (not this UTF-8 slang)?

Comment: Try using decode() method of strings.

Comment: In R, try `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, we might use @Jeroen's function at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958365/6197649 , with a minor modification to deal with `\xnn` rather than `\unnnn`

```
unescape_unicode <- function(x){
  #single string only
  stopifnot(is.character(x) && length(x) == 1)

  #find matches
  m <- gregexpr("(\\\\)+x[0-9a-z]{2}", x, ignore.case = TRUE)

  if(m[[1]][1] > -1){
    #parse matches
    p <- vapply(regmatches(x, m)[[1]], function(txt){
      gsub("\\", "\\\\", parse(text=paste0('"', txt, '"'))[[1]], fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)
    }, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

    #substitute parsed into original
    regmatches(x, m) <- list(p)
  }

  x
}
```

```r
f <- tempfile()
cat("\\xc3\\x93\\xc5\\x81\n", file = f)
fpeek::peek_head(f)
#> \xc3\x93\xc5\x81

x <- readLines(f)
unlink(f)

unescape_unicode(x)
#> [1] "ÓŁ"
```

Interestingly, `stringi::stri_escape_unicode` gives a different result, seemingly misinterpreting `\xc3\x93` as two separate characters (when it *should* be just one, `"\xc3\x93" == "\u00d3"`, but I'm confused as to which convention determines that, I'd appreciate input from someone with more clarity on the subject in the comments)

```r
stringi::stri_unescape_unicode(x)
#> [1] "Ã\u0093Å\u0081"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>